# regarding understanding an regular expression example

Tags: regex

I once read the following regular expression example as

```
average\(([^\)]*)\)
```

What does this represent? Or in other words, how to understand this regular expression structure?

Comment: I think you should read up on regular expression. This is quite a basic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is matching:

```
average(what%ever&is&not_containingAAAAAAAAAclosingParenthese)
```

Also, the non escaped parentheses often describe a *group*, which is a part of the regex that you would maybe want to extract.

If you had the following text

```
This boy entered a pub and average(Hello I'm the group) ordered a beer.
```

Your regex would match the

```
average(Hello I'm the group)
```

part. 
Once matched, you could extract the

```
Hello I'm the group
```

because you're regex defines a group:

```
([^\)]*)
```

**Explanation:**

( ) [ ] * ^ are special characters, regarding regex, but you can escape them with a backslash \ to use them as the character itself.

[^)] : matches a character class of any character not being a closing parenthese. 
[^)]* : matches an undefined number (0..n) of characters from this class.

Hope it helps, don't know if it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

[^)]   means any character but )

the character * means eventually repeated

() match themselves

\(...\) identify a part of the expression to be later accessed

Comment: I think it's the other way around. \( \) should match ( and ), and () should define an expression, group, to be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few sites that are great resources for understanding and learning regular expressions. Just paste in your regular expression and out comes and explanation.

My favorite one is [regexper.com](http://regexper.com):

[image]

There's also [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), which gives you character by character explanations of what's going on, along with a handy reference at the bottom:

[image]